# Cosa significa "filetto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Quel che mi salvò dagli arresti perpetui fu la mia riputazione di cestista, il tenente Ruggiero mi affidò l'istruzione della squadra della compagnia. Compagnia o plotone? forse reggimento? che cosa comanda un tenente? Non lo sapevo e non lo seppi mai, come mai arrvai a distinguere i **filetti** dalle losanghe, i maggiori dai colonnelli.

Malgrado aver letto tutte le [accezioni del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/filetto/),
non capisco cosa intenda l'autore per "filetti" in questo brano né perché li paragoni alle losanghe. Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "filetti" nel testo precedente?

Comment: Credo che, all'epoca in cui Gassman fece il servizio militare, i gradi fossero simili a quelli ancor oggi adoperati nell'aeronautica militare: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradi_e_qualifiche_dell%27Aeronautica_Militare

Comment: In che arma prestò servizio Gassman? Esercito, marina o aviazione? I gradi sono in parte diversi, ma in ogni caso sembra che Gassman si riferisca alle barre dei marescialli, che credo siano simili in tutte le armi. (Comunque sembra anche a me che le losanghe permettano di identificare l'aeronautica.)

Comment: @DaG: Nei granatieri.

Comment: Grazie, @Charo. In effetti è coerente col fatto che era piuttosto alto. I granatieri sono una specialità della fanteria, che ovviamente fa parte dell'esercito. Ma allora ho il dubbio su che cosa intenda per losanghe: forse i [gradi dei caporali e dei sergenti](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradi_e_qualifiche_dell%27Esercito_Italiano) che, volendo, sono dei mezzi rombi.

Comment: Ma *riputazione* e *commanda* sono scritti così nel testo?

Comment: @N74: "Riputazione" è scritto così, ma "commanda" era un errore che ho già corretto. Grazie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si parla dei gradi militari, per esempio vedi il grado di colonnello nel paramano in foto (questi credo fossero ancora usati ai tempi di Gassman):

[image]

Trovi il gallone con 3 filetti, il più alto forma l'occhiello (per essere precisi la losanga vera e propria appartiene all'Aeronautica[image]... la Marina ha il giro di bitta [image] ed il colonnello si chiama capitano di vascello).
Il tenente colonnello ha due filetti ed il maggiore ne ha uno solo. Poi togli il doppio binario e ricominci la tiritera per gli ufficiali inferiori.

La terminologia cambia con gli anni, credo che sia dopo il suo periodo comunque, i gradi al paramano spariscono ad alcuni livelli, i filetti diventano binari ed il filetto diventa quello che separa i galloni dei gradi più bassi dove il colore del filetto ha un suo significato.
Quindi se prendi un sergente hai un gallone dorato separato da filetti neri:

[image]  (nella foto è un sergente maggiore: due filetti neri)

Quando io ero militare i gradi li facevano imparare tutti, indipendentemente dal corpo di appartenenza, e quindi sapevi cosa era la losanga, l'occhiello, il binario, ecc. Quello che Gassman intende è che non si è mai preso la briga di imparare niente a riguardo i gradi: né terminologia né il distinguere un grado dall'altro, quindi non sapeva che differenza c'era tra filetti e losanghe o tra un maggiore ed un colonnello.

PS: per un po' di teatralità sta esagerando, ovviamente sa cosa è una losanga in generale e non ci si mette tanto a capire cosa è guardando i gradi militari, pure se uno se ne frega altamente basta essere militare un pochino per cominciare a riconoscere i gradi visto che li vedi continuamente ed ovviamente saprà che un tenente non comanda un reggimento.

Comment: Ottima risposta (anche se personalmente avrei fatto a meno del soggettivo poscritto: chi siamo noi per sapere che cosa sapeva o riconosceva Gassman veramente?).

Comment: @DaG, visto la sua carriera e vita dubito che non sapesse cosa fosse una losanga. Le cose di cui parla sono piuttosto comuni quando si è in divisa ed anche la recluta più menefreghista le assorbe anche se non vuole perché le ha sempre sotto il naso, diventa anche una questione di necessità imparare a chi rivolgerti se serve qualche favore. Lui stesso si definiva perfezionista. Non prendo il passaggio letteralmente ma piuttosto come descrizione di un certo atteggiamento. Come dire "non so niente di automobili, non so distinguere il volante dal cambio" pur avendo la patente.

Comment: È la tua opinione, e in buona parte anche la mia, ma qui stiamo parlando di lingua italiana, non stiamo psicanalizzando Gassman. :-)

Comment: @DaG, non lo prendo come psicanalizzare Gassman, piuttosto come capire cosa intende scrivendo il passaggio in quel modo. Dopotutto Charo chiedeva anche come mai accoppia filetto e losanga. Ha scelto due elementi molto diversi e non sono sicuro sia una scelta casuale. Per me dà un certo effetto a tutto il passaggio. Non darebbe la stessa idea se fossero elementi simili e facili da confondere. Magari è solo impressione mia... Se poi ci si limita al vocabolario la risposta sarebbe stata solo una foto con una freccia ad indicare i filetti.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: È da tenere conto che Gassman fece la recluta per solo un paio di mesi.

Comment: @Charo, credimi, bastano un paio di settimane. Poi la sua storia la hai sottomano, se ricordo bene era pure alla scuola ufficiali di Forlì, dove c'era il corso per gli ufficiali granatieri, prima di essere lasciato a casa per malattia.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Sì, è così.